# Book in which children traveled between worlds with colored rings?

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read a book at some point in school in which children travelled between worlds with colored rings, I don't know why, but I have always remembered this and am very curious as to the name of her book, can anyone help?

Comment: You say "her book"; does that mean you remember it being by a female author? If so, maybe edit the question to add that information.

Comment: Why is the time-travel tag on here?  Cassie, _was_ there any time travel in the book?  If so, please describe it in the question

Comment: In Craig Shaw Gardner's Cineverse Cycle, plastic toy "Captain Crusader decoder rings" were used to travel between B-movie-styled worlds. But the protagonists weren't children.

Comment: Some time reference would be helpful here. Depending on when you were a child, some books may be excluded.

Answer (score 43):

It sounds like you're describing "[The Magician's Nephew](http://browseinside.harpercollinschildrens.com/index.aspx?isbn13=9780060234973)" by C.S.Lewis.

Per the [Narnia wiki](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_ring);

> The Magic Rings of Andrew Ketterley were a small collection of yellow and green finger rings, which he had created, to respectively transport people to and from the Wood between the Worlds.

Comment: The Magician's Nephew was going to be my guess!

Comment: Dammit, the one time I could've got an identificaton question!

Comment: @Sweeneyrod - actually "Spaceling" seems a pretty solid answer too, and worthy of upvotes

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like *[Spaceling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2638957410)* by Doris Pischeria to me.  I remember reading this book many years ago.

> The ability to see other-dimensional rings that float in Earth's atmosphere was a late mutation of a few space-age humans. Daryl was under the care of the institution for muters, and she had discovered that if you jumped through the right ring at the right time it would land you in another dimensional world and another shape.

Comment: What about Spaceling matches up with the description in the question?

Comment: @phantom42 - I've edited in the blurb from the book

Comment: The rings they went through were differently colored, with the distinctive shades corresponding to locations in the worlds they led to. The main character transforms into lifeforms appropriate for the worlds as she goes through the rings.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that came to mind for me was The Seventh Tower Series, but I'm not sure it perfectly matches the description (as far as I can remember there were colored rings in the series, but I don't think they were particularly central to the plot).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seventh_Tower

Comment: The rings weren't colored, but the sunstones set in the rings were - and the sunstones are the series' main phlebotinum, the thing that makes everything work

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are referring to the book "The Magician's Nephew" which is the first book in "The Chronicles of Narnia" series by C.S. Lewis. The children, Polly and Digory used yellow rings to get to different worlds and green rings to return to their own.

My reference for this information was just having read the book.

Comment: Nineteen people have upvoted the answer which says exactly the same thing as yours, 16 hours ago ^^